# Can I move one folder from c:\ProgramData to different drive using junction?

Tags: junction, directory-junction

i`m using win 10, Can I move one folder from c:\ProgramData to different drive using junction and keep software which has data in that folder fully functional? and please can you write how to write a command. Thank you.

Comment: Yes;  Its possible.  What have you tried?  What problem are you trying to fix by creating a junction point for a file within ProgramData?

Answer (score -1):

It can be done, but it is strongly disrecommended, as it causes breakage in Windows 8 and later - See the Wikipedia page on [NTFS Junction Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point), most specifically the section on [limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point#Limitations).